# Dagger hilt & oauth interceptor - How to update Singleton

Tags: android, oauth, retrofit, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt for dependency injection. I'm trying to implement a oauth interceptor that will authenticate my request after login.

The problem I am having is related to the `oauthManager(context).getToken()`, etc. `OauthManager` is essentially just a class for accessing `EncryptedSharedPreferences`. But since my provides method is a `Singleton`, any updates I make to the shared prefs will not reflect to my okhttp instance.

The app starts out not authenticated, and becomes at a later point. I can probably solve this using another scope like `ViewModelScoped`, but I want to know if there's a better way of updating the oauth credentials.

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named(NAME_WITH_OAUTH)
fun provideOkHttp(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context
) = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .addInterceptor(
            OauthInterceptor(
                consumerKey = Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                consumerSecret = Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET,
                accessToken = oauthManager(context).getToken(),
                accessSecret = oauthManager(context).getSecret(),
                verifier = oauthManager(context).getVerifier()
            )
        )
        .build()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is hardly hilt problem, but structural problem.

You are passing the arguments to the Interceptor way ahead, instead when needed.

You need to inject the `Interceptor` instead of creating the instance as you down.

```kotlin
@Provides fun provideMyInterceptor(authManager : AuthManager){
    return OAuthInterceptor(
                consumerKey = Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                consumerSecret = Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET,
                authManager = authManager)

}

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named(NAME_WITH_OAUTH)
fun provideOkHttp(oAuthInterceptor : OAuthInterceptor) = OkHttpClient
        .Builder().addInterceptor(oAuthInterceptor).build()
```

Interceptor class should depend on your `AuthManager`.

```kotlin
class OAuthInterceptor(
     private val consumerKey : String,
     private val consumerSecret : String,
     private val authManager : AuthManager)

private val accessToken get() = authManager.getAccessToken()

/** other code reducted **/
```

Please note that getter will call `getAccessToken()` each time the property is accessed.

Alternatively, you can use `Provider<String>` for your token. Calling `tokenProvider.get()` will request the `Provider` to supply new snapshot of that instance each call.